# How is CTTypesetterCreateLineWithOffset different from CTTypesetterCreateLine?

Tags: ios4, core-text

The docs say that calling `CTTypesetterCreateLine` is the same as calling `CTTypesetterCreateLineWithOffset` with `offset` set to 0.0, but the description of what `offset` means is rather lacking: "The line position offset."

I've tried providing different values to it and it doesn't seem to have any impact on the typographic bounds or image bounds of the resulting `CTLineRef`, nor does it seem to affect the result of drawing the line using `CTLineDraw`. Can anyone clue me in as to the purpose of this extra parameter?

Comment: I've observed similar behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The offset is a tab offset.  It doesn't apply to the line as a whole, but to the first tab-stop.

From http://lists.apple.com/archives/Coretext-dev/2011/Feb/msg00021.html

You create a string containing a tab like "A[tab]B" with Tab position at 200.
When you create a line with offset Zero and draw it at (x, y), it will appear like this.

```
A             B
(x,y)         (x+200,y)
```

When you create a line with offset 50 and draw it at (x + 50, y) (← you need to adjust X coordinate yourself), it will appear like this,
    A          B
    (x+50,y)   (x+200,y)

Note that "B" remains at the same position even though the line starts at a different position.  If you were passing offset 0 and draw it at (x + 50, y), it would have been like the following.

```
A                B
(x+50,y)         (x+250,y)
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains it perfectly.